# SQL Access denied when accessing virtual host

Tags: mysql, sql, iphone, apache, wamp

Im trying to access my localhost website on my phone. My host files are set up like so:

httpd-vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:\path"
ServerName 192.xxx.x.xx
</VirtualHost>
```

etc/hosts:

```
192.xxx.x.xx C:\path
```

The ip above is the one obtained using ipconfig

When I try to access the ip with my phone or laptop, I get MYSQL error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] 
Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in C:path/DatabaseDriverMysql.php
```

I also tried setting up xip.io path like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:\path"
ServerName mysite.195.xxx.x.xx.xip.io
</VirtualHost>
```

But accessing it on my phone or laptop produces same error.

PS: I'm using WAMP server.

Comment: Have you checked that the `username` you are using is allowed to connect from `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` If you check how the 'root' userid is configured to allow access from all those 3 and duplicate it, you should be ok. Of course you will also need to grant the correct pribilages to the database you are using to that user account as well.

Comment: I did, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual host definition is hardly complete but this is definitely wrong

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:\path"
ServerName 192.xxx.x.xx
</VirtualHost>
```

Change it to

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:/path"           <-- changed line
ServerName 192.xxx.x.xx
</VirtualHost>
```